# solve for the lowest value of $k$ in ${n}\choose {k}$ $\geq$ $x$ , given $x$ and $n$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, factorial

Let's suppose that $n = 10$ and $x = 500$. I want to find the smallest value of $k$ for which ${n}\choose {k}$ $\geq$ $x$

I *can* check for all values of $k$ from $1$ to $n/2$ and pick the least one which produces an ${n}\choose {k}$ greater than or equal to $x$ (or alternatively I can use an efficient search algorithm like binary-search, that's beside the point), but I wanted to know if I could solve the inequality for a formula that spits out the exact value immediately.

This is for a python program, so I want to minimize run-time as much as possible.

Comment: The largest value of the binomial coefficient is $252$. Thus it can never be larger or equal to $500$. That was easy to evaluate-without any usage of python.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that. that's why I said $n / 2$. I want to find the exact formula.

Comment: You haven´t said that, sorry.  Please don´t complain.

Comment: If $n$ is even you calculate $f(n/2)=\binom{n}{\frac{n}2}$. If  $f(n/2)>x$ you calculate $f(n/2-1)$ and prove if $f(n/2-1)>x$ and so on. So $k$ starts at $n/2$  and decreases by 1 at every iteration step. The same can be done if $n$ is uneven.

Comment: Thanks, guess this is the closest I can get to a formula

Comment: I think that too. May be you can divide $k=0$ to $n/2$ in, for instance, $4$ sub-intervals like  $[0,n/8], (n/8,n/4],(n/4, 3/8n],(3/8,n/2]$ and see in which interval the inequality is fulfilled.

Comment: This might be better suited to https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Yes I thought of posting this to stackoverflow but I thoought it was more math-related

Answer (score 1):

From a computing point of view, I think I should treat the problem using algebra considering $k$ as a continuous variable considering first
$$\binom{n}{k}=x \implies \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=x\implies\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n+1-k)}=x$$ and then search for the zero of function
$$f(k)=\log (\Gamma (n+1-k))+\log (\Gamma (k+1))-A$$ where $A=\log (\Gamma (n+1))-\log(x)$. Newton method would be quite efficient and starting iterating at $k_0=0$, by Darboux theorem, the solution would be reach without any overshoot.

The first iterate would be 
$$k_1=\frac{\log (\Gamma (n+1))-A}{H_n}$$ (which I should probably not use at all) and just use
$$k_{m+1}=k_m-\frac{f(k_m)}{f'(k_m)}$$ where $f'(k_m)$ would be computed using finite differences. This means that only one single function is required.

Let us try for $n=100$ and $x=12345678987654321$. For this case, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & k_m \\
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 7.14274 \\
 2 & 12.4175 \\
 3 & 13.2797 \\
 4 & 13.2972 \\
 5 & 13.2973
\end{array}
\right)$$

Remember that function $\color{red}{\text{lgamma(x)}}$ is available in Python library.